MERN stack app returns 404 error when submitting registration form
I'm developing a sign-up page using the MERN stack, and I'm encountering a 404 error when I try to submit the form. The error message is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".
I'm using axios to send a POST request to the /api/user/signup endpoint, and I've confirmed that the endpoint is defined correctly in the userRoute.js file. I'm also using antd for the form components, react-hot-toast for notifications, and react-router-dom for routing. I'm not sure what's causing the 404 error, and I would appreciate any help in troubleshooting the issue.
the server is listening on port 5000
Here's the relevant code:
//Signup.jsx
import React from "react";
import {Form, Input, Select, Button} from 'antd';
import logo from '../assets/logo.png';
import "./Signup.css"
import axios from 'axios';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
function Signup(){
   const onFinish =async(values) => {
    try{
      const response = await axios.post('/api/user/signup', values);
      if(response.data.success){
        toast.success(response.data.message);

      }else{
        toast.error(response.data.message);

      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("quelque chose s'est mal passé");

    }
   };
  return(
    <div className="allcontainer">
    <div className="cont">
       <div className="thelogo">
         <img src={logo}/>
       </div>
      <Form onFinish={onFinish}>
       <div className="formulaire-content">
       <div className="login-form">
          <div className="title">Bienvenue!</div>
          <div className="boxes">
            <Form.Item label='Nom' name='nom'>
              <Input placeholder='Nom' />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label='Prenom' name='prenom'>
              <Input placeholder='Prenom' />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label='E-mail' name='email'>
              <Input placeholder='E-mail'  autoComplete="email" />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label='Mot de passe' name='motdepasse'>
              <Input placeholder='Mot de passe' />
            </Form.Item> 
            <Form.Item label='Telephone' name='telephone'>
              <Input placeholder='Telephone' />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label='Type de compte' name='typedecompte'>
            <Select className="selecttype" placeholder="Type de compte">
              <Select.Option value="Responsable">Secrétaire</Select.Option>
              <Select.Option value="Radiologue">Radiologue</Select.Option>
              <Select.Option value="Technicien en imagerie">Technicien en imagerie</Select.Option>
              <Select.Option value="Patient">Patient</Select.Option>
            </Select>
            </Form.Item>
            <div className="button input-box">
              <Button htmlType="submit">Créer compte</Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </Form>
    </div>
    </div>
  );

}
export default Signup

//server.js
const express= require("express");
require("dotenv").config();
const app= express();
const dbConfig = require("./config/dbConfig");
app.use(express.json());
const userRoute = require("./routes/userRoute");

app.use('/api/user' , userRoute);
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`listening on port ${port}`));

//userRoute.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
        if (userExists) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: "user already exists", success: false })
        }
        const password = req.body.motdepasse;
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        req.body.password = hashedPassword;
        const newuser = new User(req.body);
        await newuser.save();
        res.status(200).send({ message: "user created successfully", success: true });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Error creating user", success: false, error});
    }
});

//router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
   // try {
    //} catch (error) { }
//});

module.exports = router;

I've checked the URL, the server logs, and the User model, and everything seems to be correct.
I think the the Frontend application fails to access to the backend resource at the specified URL
